# Enable Azure devops pipeline to assign a role to an Azure resource

Tags: azure, azure-devops, rbac

I need to execute a PowerShell script that along other stuff assigns role to an Azure Automation Account to be a Data Factory Contributor

```
#Configure Access to data factory:
$accountObj = Get-AzAutomationAccount -Name "$objectName" -ResourceGroupName 
"$resourceGroupName"
$identityId = ($accountObj).Identity.PrincipalId
$scope="/subscriptions/<subscrId>/resourceGroups/resGrp/
   providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/ADF"
```

According
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#user-access-administrator

to assign a role to a resource.
(In my case Allow Automation Account be a Data Factory Contributor )

The script works fine when I Run it as myself (Owner) from Azure Portal - Posershell cloud

However, I need it to run from the Azure DevOps pipeline, and I already have a set of pipelines that create various resources, by running Powershell scripts.
I get an error at the stage where I call the command.  - Task to create automation account, and to import Runbooks works fine.
[image: ADO Error]

I understand that my Azure Pipeline needs to be allowed to assign role, but .. how can I add permission to it I do not know.

I look here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#user-access-administrator

But, I do not have that

> "roleName": "User Access Administrator", when searching for it, to assign to dev ops pipeline.

So, far my ADO pipeline has a role of "Contributor".  This way I can create Azure data factory, crete Key Vaults and secrets in it.  .. as well as create the Automation account and its run books.

And this is where I am lost ... what am i looking for?..
From the debug output, the line that fails is a call to

```
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $identityId -RoleDefinitionName ($role).Name -Scope $scope
```

Comment: You need to assign User Access Administrator to the service principal that's backing your service connection. If you can't see the User Access Administrator role, you might not have sufficient access to assign it.

Answer (score 0):

> The error usually occurs if your DevOps service principal does not have **User Access Administrator** role that is required for assigning  roles.

When I ran the below script in my DevOps pipeline having **`Contributor`** role, I too got **same error** like this:

```
$accountObj = Get-AzAutomationAccount -Name "sriautomationacc2609" -ResourceGroupName "rgname"
$identityId = ($accountObj).Identity.PrincipalId$scope="/subscriptions/subId/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/ADF"
$roleName = "Data Factory Contributor"
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $identityId -RoleDefinitionName $roleName -Scope $scope
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, visit `Service connections` tab and click on **Manage service principal** option like this:

[image]

It opens Azure Portal with your **DevOps service principal** page where you can find service principal name:

[image]

Now, assign **User Access Administrator** role to the Azure DevOps service principal under your subscription like this.

[image]

When I ran my DevOps pipeline again after assigning **`User Access Administrator`** role, I got **response** successfully like this:

```
$accountObj = Get-AzAutomationAccount -Name "sriautomationacc2609" -ResourceGroupName "rgname"
$identityId = ($accountObj).Identity.PrincipalId$scope="/subscriptions/subId/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/ADF"
$roleName = "Data Factory Contributor"
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $identityId -RoleDefinitionName $roleName -Scope $scope
```

**Response:**

[image]

As you already have **Owner** role, you can also run below PowerShell command in Azure Cloud Shell to assign role to DevOps service principal:

```
(Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName <DevOpsAppname>).id
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId <DevOpSpId> -RoleDefinitionName "User Access Administrator" -Scope "/subscriptions/subId/"
```

**Response:**

[image]